# No Suitable Constructor Found (Java)

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to compile my program here, but I am running into a small error and the error is "no suitable constructor found for ComplexNumber(double)." Here is my code so far.

```
public class ComplexNumber extends ImaginaryNumber
{
    private double realCoefficient;

    public ComplexNumber ( )
    {
        super ( );
        this.realCoefficient = 1;
    }

    public ComplexNumber (double r, double i)
    {
        super (i);
        this.realCoefficient = r;
    }

    public ComplexNumber add (ComplexNumber another)
    {
        return new ComplexNumber (this.realCoefficient + another.realCoefficient); //the error at complile occurs here, right at new.
    }//More Codes
```

I have had this problem once, and that was because I did not have a parameterized constructor. However this time, I do have one. So I have no idea what is the problem this time.

Here is my code for the ImaginaryNumber

```
public class ImaginaryNumber implements ImaginaryInterface
{
//Declaring a variable.
protected double coefficient;

//Default constructor.
public ImaginaryNumber( )
{
    this.coefficient = 1;
}

//Parameterized constructor.
public ImaginaryNumber(double number)
{
    this.coefficient = number;
}

//Adding and returing an imaginary number.
public ImaginaryNumber add (ImaginaryNumber another)
{
    return new ImaginaryNumber(this.coefficient + another.coefficient);
}//More Codes
```

My ImaginaryNumber class works fine.

Comment: Post the code of the `ImaginaryNumber` class.

Comment: When you've got a primitive type as an argument you can't expect it to be promoted to any other kind of type than the 'autoboxed' type. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `add` method, you are attempting to pass exactly one parameter to a constructor, but you only have constructors that take 0 or 2 parameters.

It looks like you need to add the imaginary parts of the `ComplexNumber` anyway, so place that imaginary part addition in as the second parameter to the constructor.

Using the `coefficient` protected variable from `Imaginary`:

```
return new ComplexNumber (this.realCoefficient + another.realCoefficient,
                          this.coefficient + another.coefficient);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I was just confused with how my professor was explaining it in class today.

Answer (score 2):

Java is looking for a constructor of just:

```
public ComplexNumber(double d){
   //to-do
}
```

You will need to make a constructor that fits those arguments.

Comment: While that would satisfy the compiler, the complex number addition would be incorrect; the imaginary parts would need to be added and stored in the new complex number as well.